Question about CVE-2024-2961 PHP Bug (iconv issue)
I've seen a bunch of news about this bug, does it affect applications that do not use the iconv() function?

How could a bug in a function affect programs that don't use that function? Of course, it's possible that you call other library functions that use it without your knowledge.

It could also be leveraged if the PHP app has a code execution vulnerability that lets the attacker run arbitrary code.

Even if your app uses iconv(), it doesn't mean it's vulnerable. This issue is related to a legacy Chinese encoding (ISO-2022-CN-EXT) and I doubt you are using it.

my understanding based on all of the speculation i have read was that something in PHP itself (or possibly some very widely used function in PHP), eg parsing of HTTP headers, was calling the affected function in such a way that could be controlled by a user, rather than if you are using some very obscure feature of PHP in a risky way then you were affected
so far though all the information we have is someone trying to get some attention for their conference and then speculation based on that

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Even if you don't call it directly, it might be called indirectly by library functions that you call.
See how to identify all libc calls at compile time? for how you can determine if your application calls a specific function in libc.

Is there list of known functions that call iconv()?

Of course not. Who could compile a list of all libraries and applications anyone has written, and then cross-reference them to every function they call?
